# How am I supposed to make a LifecycleNode in rclcpp?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The implementation of my next node fits well with the LifecycleNode pattern, so I thought I would implement one using it. I go to the rclcpp GitHub page and ask myself, what do I need to inherit from the LifecycleNode and perform all transitions properly? The GitHub page refers me to the API page (https://docs.ros2.org/latest/api/rclcpp_lifecycle/). It looks a lot like an API page, not a tutorial page. Maybe I am not good enough at reading API's, but I sure could not figure out how to make a LifecycleNode based on looking around the API.

I am also referred to the design documents, which do give an idea of what the rclcpp implementation needs, but not necessarily what I as a user need.

I am also referred to the quality declaration, where rclcpp_lifecycle intends to be a Quality Level 1 category, which includes all *kinds* of documentation.

Is there a decent guide or example available that I just missed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410405/how-am-i-supposed-to-make-a-lifecyclenode-in-rclcpp?/) by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2022-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Searching for `lifecycle` on `docs.ros.org` leads to [Managing nodes with managed lifecycles](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Demos/Managed-Nodes.html), which points to [ros2/demos/humble/lifecycle](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/humble/lifecycle).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) on 2022-12-12**:
That's a good place to end, thanks for providing the link. For the record, when I searched for `lifecycle` on `docs.ros.org` I mainly got links to change logs and release posts. It's there, but I hope you agree that this is not particularly ergonomic. A link from the GitHub readme would not be too much, I think.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-12-12**:
Sure.

I would suggest you post this as an issue on the `rclcpp` repository's tracker.

It's not going to have good visibility as a comment / question on ROS Answers.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-12-13**:
Looks like you did that: [ros2/rclcpp#2064](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/2064).

**Comment by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) on 2022-12-13**:
Yep! Thanks for guidance.